# Visual Studio 2013 Find and Replace in Current Selection

Tags: visual-studio-2013, replace, find, selection

I can't seem to find the find and replace in a current selection in `Visual Studio 2013 - Community Edition`.

Does it have this kind of functionality?

The only choices when I press **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>`+`<kbd>Shift</kbd>`+`<kbd>F</kbd>** are the following-

[image]

Comment: Possibly related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34863453/how-to-set-selection-scope-of-search-replace-in-vs-2015

Comment: it doesn't make sense to limit the scope to the selection when you're doing a multi-file search.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try selecting some text (ie. your current selection), and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd> (find and replace shortcut).  Below is a VS 2010 screenshot, however VS 2013 works the same; the only major difference is the dialog box.

[image]

Comment: To expand on that, the standard for menus is to grey-out unavailable options. Visual Studio instead removes "In Current Selection" if you have no selection. A nice explanation of the confusion: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/110169/should-unavailable-options-be-grayed-out-or-invisible-to-users