# How to set "Selection" scope of search & replace in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

When I select a text block in text editor and open the search & replace window (Ctrl+H), the search & replace scope is set to "Selection" automatically in VS 2013 and the olders.

In VS 2015, the scope is always set to "Current document".

I've not found any information about this change. Does anybody know it is a bug or a feature (and can it be re-configured to the former behavior somehow)?

Comment: Seems like a bug to me.  Will continue searching to see if I can find an answer, as this has been driving me crazy!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Tools / Options / Environment / Find and Replace / check `Automatically limit search to selection` option.  See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165349.aspx)

Comment: And what's bugging me now is that despite the setting being set, it keeps acting as though it's not, and I have to go clear it and re-set it to make it work right again. Frustrating!

Comment: @ErikE what plug-ins / extensions are you running? Seems to me that, every time I run a major update (or something updates behind the scenes) a series of settings get tweaked.  Also, is this on every re-start of VS, or does it hold for awhile & then lose its mind?

Comment: My setting reverted itself after working for a while, so yeah probably updating messes with it.