# Visual Studio 2015 Find dialog loses selection and no longer defaults to search Selection

Tags: visual-studio-2015, finddialog

In Visual Studio 2015, when I select some text and press <kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+H</kbd>, it doesn't default to search within the Selection. This is a huge breaking change to my workflow.

Additionally, it seems like sometimes it even *removes* my selection, though I haven't confirmed this for sure (I use the dark theme and sometimes it's hard to tell what's selected).

Is there any way to get the old behavior back, where if I launch the find dialog with a selection in the active window, it defaults to search within "Selection" instead of "Current Document"?

For those who want to get in on the action, I've [reported this as a **bug** at Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2491417).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set "Selection" scope of search & replace in VS 2015](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34863453/how-to-set-selection-scope-of-search-replace-in-vs-2015)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had no idea this was a setting! The solution is as simple as checking a box—Go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Find and Replace and check "Automatically limit search to selection".

[image: Visual Studio 2015 option to limit search to selection.]

Microsoft has acknowledged this change in behavior from the previous version—I received an email that Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 will have this option set by default for fresh installations.

Thank you, Microsoft!

Comment: I have observed Visual Studio 2017 reverting this setting on its own, probably due to an update installation.